# Separate /home partitions for different users

Tags: debian, usb, accounts

I have a debian system with separate /root and /home partitions.
I already have some user accounts in /home partition.
I need another user account in that system. The problem is that I would like to have /home partition for it on a portable usb disk.

The idea is that if the usb is not plugged in, then I am only able to log as one of the local users. If the usb is plugged in, system should detect it, mount the usb partition and allow me to log also as portableUser giving me the access to its configuration files.

What would be the simplest way to do it? Two approaches come to my mind:

a) symlinking usbdisk/portableUser directory to /home/portableUser directory

b) mounting usbdisk as a /home partition in fstab, but.. will it be possible to mount it and to have access to the 'local' /home partition user accounts?

I played the whole day with fstab and symlinks but with no success. Neither I was able to find any straightforward description how to do it. Any help appreciated, ideally in the form of bash commands... :)

Comment: Are you asking how to mount a specific removable filesystem to `/home/portableUser` automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the USB's mount point. Instead just change the `HOME` directory for your `portableuser` so that it's on the mounted USB.

For example, if your USB mounts as `/media/portable`, create the user account with their `HOME` directory as `/media/portable/portableuser`.

This won't stop `portableuser` logging in, though; to do that I would use a variation on the login shell. Here's a worked example.

1. Assume the USB mounts as `/media/portable`.
2. Create the `portableuser` with home directory `/media/portable/portableuser` and login shell `/usr/local/bin/bash-if-mounted`. Here's the entry from `/etc/passwd`:

   ```
   portableuser:x:1004:1004:Portable user:/media/portable/portableuser:/usr/local/bin/bash-if-mounted
   ```
3. Create the executable shell script `/usr/local/bin/bash-if-mounted` as follows:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   #
   # bash-if-mounted
   ################################################################
   #
   name="${0##*/}"
   shell=$(type -p "${name%%-*}" 2>/dev/null)


   if [[ -d "$HOME" ]]
   then
       [[ -n "$shell" ]] && export SHELL="$shell"

       exec "$SHELL" "$@"
       echo "No shell" >&2
   else
       echo "No home directory at $HOME" >&2
   fi

   sleep 2
   exit 1
   ```
4. Test with and without the directory `/media/portable/portableuser` existing.

If you want to use a shell other than `bash`, rename the executable accordingly (eg `dash-if-mounted`, `zsh-if-mounted`).

Answer (score 0):

As asked this is probably impossible with *current* code.

The software toolchain that does authentication and logging is seperate from the toolchain that handles automounting.

What you *might* be able to do is play with UniounFS-FUSE and (assuming bash) your bashrc files to check for the presence of a USB filesystem with a specific UUID (or whatever) and union mount it at login.

Alternatively give up on the notion of requiring the disk to be mounted to log in, and just have your /etc/fstab mount that particular on /home/portableUser and have a .bashrc file that just has "logout" in it. That way if the USB disk isn't mounted a login will trigger an immediate logout. If it is mounted (with a non-union mount) the .bashrc will be masked by the mounted file system (test this, it's entirely from memory of a different problem 15 years ago) and the login will succeed.

Also note that you can set portableUser's home directory to anything, it doesn't have to be in /home, it can be wherever the disk would normally be mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your reponses. In the end, problem was not where I suspected it to be. It turned out that I was able to log in to system in the text mode shell. It was only KDE that froze on login.
My USB partition is just a clone of /home partition from my office computer where I have Debian Buster installed (with plasmashell 5.14.5) and I wanted to mount it on my home laptop where I had Ubuntu 16 with plasmashell 5.5.5. Now I believe that some incompatibility between those two versions of KDE was the reason of my problems, because now, after installing Buster on my home laptop, everything works fine if I add just two lines in fstab

```
UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx...    /mnt/portableUserUSB  ext4  nofail    0   2
/mnt/portableUserUSB/portableUser /home/portableUser none bind,nofail 0 0
```

(nofail parameter is important!)

Comment: It's good that you've solved your problem. However for next time please notice that the solution you've described here has no bearing on the question you actually asked. There's no mention of KDE in your question, for example, and certainly nothing about it hanging. What's happened here is that you've asked an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).